# How does DateTime.Parse() work in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, cultureinfo

I know that DateTime parsing can be tricky, but since there are a lot of mechanisms are relying on `DateTime.Parse()` especially its `DateTime.Parse(string)` overload, I think it makes sense to understand how does it work under the hood and how does it behave on different inputs.

What we know:

MSDN [states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Culture) when you use the `DateTime.Parse(String)` overload, the formatting is derived from the CurrentThread.Culture, however it draws the attention:

- culture-specific data can change (and it did) between the different versions of the framework
- the culture-specific data can be overridden by the OS settings
- `DateTime.Parse()` tries to be smart

Because of these it's a bit hard for me to predict what will be result when somebody calls this function on different user inputs.

Even when I specify a culture, `DateTime.Parse` can recognize strings as valid DateTimes what you might not think to recognize. For example, all the following dates are valid - here are some of my findings:

```
var at = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-AT", false);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = at;

// it doesn't care about the order:
DateTime.Parse("21.12.2020", at).Dump();
DateTime.Parse("2020.12.31", at).Dump();

// it accepts multiple separators:
DateTime.Parse("2020,12,31", at).Dump();
DateTime.Parse("2020/12/31", at).Dump();
DateTime.Parse("2020 12 31", at).Dump();

// it accepts multiple separators even in a single string:
DateTime.Parse("1999/12-31", at).Dump();

// year must consist at least 3 digits:
DateTime.Parse("100/12-31", at).Dump();  // this works
//DateTime.Parse("99/12-31", at).Dump(); -> this doesn't
DateTime.Parse("001/12-31", at).Dump(); // but this works again (3 digits)

// trimming (well, MSDN mentions this)
DateTime.Parse("  100/12,31   ", at).Dump();
```

For me it's not so clear what's going on here. The separators `/` and `,` are not even mentioned in the `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` so I have no idea where did it come from. Are these separators hardcoded in `DateTime.Parse`? I tried to read the disassembled code, but it was a bit complex for me.

Is there any easy way to summarize what happens and which formats are supported?

I know that in a "real life example" if I have to parse a DateTime with a given format, I should use ParseExact instead, but since there are a lot of stuff relying on this (such as ASP.NET MVC model binding) I think it worths a question what it does exactly - and why does it recognize `"100/3.14"` as a valid DateTime instead of a division :)

Comment: We also know the source code. Ever bothered to use that as basis for some fact finding? And the solution for all that bad behavior is... to use ParseExact ;)

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,f75289affb7e0ce3

Comment: Portal : [`DateTime.Parse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1018)

Comment: Direct Portal : [`DateTimeParse.TryParse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2330)

Comment: Thanks for the links. However if one has a short explanation which briefly covers the main logic behind it then you don't have to interpret the whole code to get a rough idea. I'm sure that most of the people won't read through the code.

Comment: What is your end goal?  Are you trying to build some sort of validator that will determine what will be parseable?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just to have a better understanding what does it do without digging too much into the code. As you can see, I already collected some interesting examples what I discovered so far.